# Работа с массивом символов

Tags: c++, строки, символы

```
void k(char s[]){
   // s[0]='1';
   cout<<s;
}

char*c1="-1-2-3";
k(c1);
//char a[]=c1; error
```

Почему при передаче указателя в функцию получается им инициализировать массив,  а внутри мейна так уже не выходит, ведь делаем такое же присваивание?

Comment: А вы напишите `char a[] = "-1-2-3";` :) В функции *инициализации* массива нет, есть передача указателя.

Comment: @Harry , а почему нет массива, у нас же он в параметрах?

Comment: В описании параметров `char a[]` и `char *a` описывают одну и ту же сущность -- адрес памяти, элементы которой надо интерпретировать как тип `char`

Comment: Строка `char*c1="-1-2-3";` константная и любое изменение приведёт к краху памяти. А так : `char c1[]="-1-2-3";` менять буквы можно , размер - нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический массив в Си/Си++ имеет определённые особенности. Он не может иметь неопределённого размера. У него нет функции копирования и как следствие передаётся в функцию только указатель на этот массив.

Синтаксис `void k(char s[])` тихо компилятором заменяется на указатель `void k(char * s)`.

Ошибка присваивания у вас `char a[]=c1;` во первых в том, что вы массиву с неопределёнными размерами присваиваете указатель, а во вторых как я и говорил, у него нет функции копирования. Копирование надо делать функцией `strncpy` или простым циклом если тип не `char` и не забывать выставлять нужный размер.

```
strncpy ( a , c1 , 12 ) ;
```

или

```cpp
char a [ 12 ] ;
int i = 0 ;
do {
  a [ i ] = c1 [ i ] ;
  ++ i ;
} while ( i < 12 and c1 [ i - 1 ] != '\00' ) ;
```

Comment: Однако **реальная ошибка** тут в том, что это указатель на **настоящую** константу (в read-only memory). Остальные слова к делу не относятся

Comment: про константную строку я пропустил обсуждение, разбирал только строку `//char a[]=c1; error` @avp

Comment: Ну, автора же очевидно волнует вопрос, почему у него программа не работает при присваивании. А не работает, поскольку он константу хочет изменить

Comment: нет, компилятор не пускал. не в константах дело. @avp он записал массиву присвоить указатель.